# How to access the whole current record within update statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Is it possible to reference/access/pass the current record within an update statement?

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  foo text
);

CREATE FUNCTION gen_t2_foo(_a t1, _b t2) RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT _a.name || ' - ' || _b.name;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

CREATE FUNCTION upd_t2(_min_id int, _max_id int, _a t1) RETURNS VOID AS $$
  UPDATE t2 SET
    foo = gen_f2_name(_a, ???) -- How to pass the current t2 record?
    WHERE id >= _min_id AND id <= _max_id;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just refer to the table:

```
create function upd_t2(_min_id int, _max_id int, _a t1)
returns void as $$
    update t2
    set foo = gen_t2_foo (_a, t2)
    where id >= _min_id and id <= _max_id;
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: ... or within a schema using an alias `UPDATE s1.t1 r SET foo = gen_t2_foo(_a, r) ...`

Answer (score 1):

It looks that the second function is expected to create a value from the field `name` in both tables, and between a start and end indices, right? In that case, make sure that gen_t2_foo also receives an index to merge the values of a single record (in both tables). Then, you can use it as you wanted to.

By the way, why are you declaring upd_t2 as a function which returns VOID? This would be what **Procedures** are offered for.